# Exception Handling w/ Axios

Tags: exception, error-handling, axios

I have an API written in .Net that's being called from a (server-side) JavaScript app. The behavior is very odd and I can't explain.

If I hit the endpoint from Postman - with the same parameters - it works as expected (a MSSQL database is updated), and no errors.

However, when the code below is executed, even though the database is updated, the **catch** is triggered but - here's the weird part - the **err** object is **{}**, just an empty object.

Also, because the **err** object is empty (not undefined or null), the **res.status(...)** call triggers another error, obviously because there are no properties on the object.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

```
  axios.post('task', formData, { headers: formData.getHeaders() })
    .then((result) => {
      res.send(result)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('#ERROR#')
      res.status(err.response.status).send(err.response.data.Message)
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

`res.send(result.data)`

I hope it will work.